# Does there exist a mnemonic in Esperanto for the first 8 digits of pi?

Tags: phrase-requests

In English we have the following [mnemonic](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-mnemonic.html) for the first 8 digits of pi: “May I have a large container of coffee?” The digits of pi are obtained by counting the number of letters in each word:

May = 3

I = 1

have = 4

...

So, does there exist a mnemonic in Esperanto for the first 8 digits of pi?

edit: There is no requirement that the mnemonic in Esperanto follow the same pattern as the one given here in English. For example, the rule for the Esperanto mnemonic might be "Subtract 1 from the number of letters in each word." (or, 2, etc.).

Comment: slightly off topic but... this seems an inherently slow and non-scaleable solution to remembering digits... and why only 8?

Comment: @masukomi: Your comment is so sheeshish as to be troll-like. Anyway: knowing the first words of a famous poem (e.g., “To be or not to be / That is the question” is far better than not knowing any of it at all. I am basing my question on the existing popularity of this topic. If you wish to challenge the popularity of the topic, you have the right to do so, but this is not the proper venue for doing so. Most things of immediate use in life are non-scalable.

Comment: i apologize that it's trollish, you're right, and i'm not challenging the popularity, and while i get why mnemonics exist. The issue is that this one requires SO much more work than the thing it's trying to help you with. Memorize 8 words, remember one, count its letters, remember next count its letters. etc. If you also memorize the letter counts then you've memorize far more information than the thing you're trying to save effort on. Also, 8 just seems a completely random number of digits to memorize.

Comment: @masukomi: Again, your grasp of the situation is so poor as to suggest trollish intent. You don’t have to memorize the number of letters in each word; you only have to remember to COUNT the number of letters in each word after you have rolled out the mnemonic. Also, there is nothing magic about the number 8. If you would like 3 more digits, you can add “cream and sugar”. That is, “May I have a large container of coffee, cream and sugar?” gives 3.1415926535. A meaningful sentence is always easier to remember than a random sequence of digits. Only a troll, or ignoramus, would claim otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never heard of such a mnemonic before, but let’s give it a try. :-) (If you don’t like *neologismoj* you’re welcome to come up with an alternative!)

> Pro l’ olda k lanta elevatoro mi tardas

Answer (score 6):

Even if this question has already an accepted answer, 
let me link [this interesting Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piphilology) for everybody’s enjoyment.

The problem that in principle Esperanto doesn’t have one-letter words can be easily overcome applying the rules of [standard Pilish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilish): for instance, the sequence `1 2` can be encoded by a 12-letter word.

In my following attempt, however, I resorted to another trick.

> Jen:
>   **o** nom**o,**
>   **a** finaĵ’ adjektiv**a,**
>   **as** verb**as:** 
>   tiele sen manko funkcias
>   fleksebla, belsona Esperanto.

**Translation:** “Here it is: ***o*** (is a) noun, ***a*** an adjective ending, ***as*** makes verbs: flexible, nice-sounding Esperanto works in this way without shortcomings.”

**Explanation:** The trick I resorted to is simple: I used the basic endings ***o, a***  and ***as*** as independent words. This was even envisioned by Zamenhof himself, in a famous answer: *endings and suffixes are independent words*  ([here](http://eduinf.waw.pl/esp/lern/librejo/0015/lr.pdf), p.48) As a final insider joke, I used the adjectives *flexible* and *nice-sounding,* which are part of a well-known, outdated slogan from several decades ago: *simpla, fleksebla, belsona, vere internacia en siaj elementoj...* and so on.

Comment: If you would explain the trick, we would all appreciate it.

Comment: @MikeJones Done! _Farite!_

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score -1):

Mi neniam aŭdis pri tiu frazo (mia denaska lingvo ne estas la angla, sed mi studis multege da matematiko en universitato) kaj mi dubas, ke tiaj frazoj ekzistas en aliaj lingvoj, do kial oni bezonus esperantan?

Mi certas, ke oni povus elpensi tian frazon, sed… kial? Ankaŭ, Esperanto ne havas unuliterajn vortojn, tial oni devas uzi mallongigojn kiel *k* (de *kaj*, PIV uzas tiun) kaj aliajn similajn.

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev Ĉi tia (aŭ simila) frazo ekzistas en multaj lingvoj, ekz. en la bulgara „Как е леко и лесно изчислено пи всички знаят щом желаят”...