# How do you say ‘Pilish’ in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word ‘Pilish’ occurs neither in Benson, nor Wells, nor Vikivortaro, nor Vikipedio, nor ReVo, nor Sonja. Admittedly, it does not occur in Merriam-Webster nor in Wiktionary either, but I don’t see any reason why it couldn’t or shouldn’t. It does occur in [Wikipedia](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-pilish.html), however. I was unaware of the existence of this word until I saw it [mentioned by Dario](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/does-there-exist-a-mnemonic-in-esperanto-for-the-first-8-digits-of-pi) in answer to my question about a mnemonic in Esperanto for the first 8 digits of pi. My guess is that ‘Pilish’ in Esperanto would be ‘la pila’.

Comment: Technically, ***la** pila* would be ***the** pilish*.

Comment: So 'la angla' would be 'the English'? Sheesh.

Comment: No, it's short for _la angla lingvo_.

Answer (score 7):

"see any reason why it couldn’t or shouldn’t"

I see a reason: The lexicon of Esperanto must not be bloated to the unbelievable size English has.
There is also no need for an extremely rare notion like *Pilish* to have some short expression.

Esperanto has the good tradition of forming words for concepts by composition, which is much clearer than mere borrowing (**pila*, which additionally would give an awkward homonym) or also affixation (*piuma*, which still needs clarification).

For this reason I'd like to propose something like ***Pi-vortigo/-frazigo***.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to address your points, with which I basically agree.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that ***Pilish*** is a portmanteau of ***Pi*** and *Eng**lish*** (just as *[Spanglish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanglish), [Chinglish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinglish),* etc...).

In Esperanto, ***la pi-uma*** fits in several ways. First, ***-um-*** can be used to espress any unclear and unusual relationship with the root; second, the verb ***umi*** is already used to express obsessive, pointless activities like this one; third, it consists of pre-existing elements only. It is just the type of word which would be created spontaneously when two Esperantist nerds discuss such things in a *gufujo* somewhere (maybe comparing *la piuma angla* with *la piuma hungara...*)

The word *Pilish* was created in English *for fun* and *as a joke.* Obviously, in a serious context you would use the pedantic ***π-frazigo*** (as in “encoding of π into sentences”.) Neither ***π-frazigo*** nor ***piumado*** would be understandable outside context, and one can choose the appropriate register in every context.

Comment: So, if we made a portmanteau of Pi and Esperanto it would be … pisperanto? Piranto? ;-)